# Optimal strategy for urn game

Tags: probability

Suppose we have an urn with three different colour of balls: red, blue and yellow. We are only told that the percentage of blue ones is 10%.

We should pick only one ball. If it's blue we get 100 dollars, if it is red we get 20 dollars, while if we pick a yellow we lose 20 dollars.

1. What should be the percentage of red balls for the game to be gainful?
2. If a person could tell us what the colour of the ball will be, how much should be willing to pay that person?

I need to verify that my answer for the second question is correct.

For the first one, if G are the gains of the game, we can find that $p_r = P(red) > 0.2$ from $E[G] = 10 + 20p_r - 20*(1-0.1-p_r)>0$.

Is it correct to say that if we can know the colour of the ball, we have that
$E[G] = 10+20p_r,$ since we would not play if we would pick a yellow ball, and that we should be willing to pay the person telling us the outcome no more than $E[G]$?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: I think you are nor allowed to not play. Otherwise it is too easy. so you have a 0,7 probability to have the yellow ball. If you stay with 0,2 for the red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$E_0=10 + 20p_r - 20*(1-0.1-p_r)$$
be the expected value of the game with no request for information about the color of the ball, and let
$$E_1=10 + 20p_r$$
be the expected value of the game assuming you intend to ask for the color of the ball.

Let's assume you can opt not to play.

Let $x$ be the asking price to be told the color of the ball.

Then an optimal strategy is as follows . . .

If $E_0\le 0$ then

- If $x < E_1$, ask for the color (and play provided the color is not yellow).

  If $x\ge E_1$, opt not to play.

If $E_0 > 0$ then

- If $x < E_1-E_0$, ask for the color (and play provided the color is not yellow).

  If $x\ge E_1-E_0$, play without asking.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If they tell you the colour of the picked ball then

- with probability $0.1$ they tell you blue and you win $\$100$
- with probability $p_r$ they tell you red and you win $\$20$
- with probability $0.9-p_r$ they tell you yellow and you do not play

but if you would have bet anyway because $p_r>0.2$ then your gain is when they tell you yellow and the expected gain is $$20(0.9 -p_r) =18-20p_r$$ and you should be willing to pay anything below this amount.

If $p_r < 0.2$ then you would not have bet without the information, so your gain is when they tell you blue or red and you expected gain would be $10+20p_r$ and you should be willing to pay anything below this amount.

Note that the two bounds are each equal to $\$14$ when $p_r=0.2$. But  when $p_r$ is very small $(p_r \approx 0)$ then you should not be prepared to pay more than $\$10$ for the information on the colour of the picked ball and if it is very large $(p_r \approx 0.9)$ than the information is worth about $\$0$ to you.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the answer :)